# How to "log-maxsize" the uWSGI vassal logger?

Tags: django, logging, uwsgi, supervisord

i am started `uWSGI` via `supervisord` in Emperor Mode to deploy multiple Django Apps in near future. So far i only deployed one App for testing purposes.

I would like to seperate the emperor logs from my vassals. So far the loggers work. Except that i can not apply `log-maxsize` to my vassals `logger` - thats also applies to my vassals `req-logger`.

### [uwsgi]

```
[program:uwsgi]
command=uwsgi 
    --master 
    --emperor %(ENV_HOME)s/etc/uwsgi/vassals
    --logto %(ENV_HOME)s/logs/uwsgi/emperor/emperor.log
    --log-maxsize 20
    --enable-threads
    --log-master

<...autostart etc...>
```

[garden_app] - vassal

```
<...>
; ---------
; # Logger #
; ---------
; diable default req log and set request Log 
req-logger = file:%(var_logs)/vassal_garden/garden_request.log
disable-logging = true
log-4xx = true
log-5xx = true
log-maxsize = 20
; set app / error Log
logger = file:%(var_logs)/vassal_garden/garden_app.log
log-maxsize = 20
<...>
```

---

As you can see i set the `log-maxsize` very low to see the effects immediately.

First of all - all logs working separately.
However, while my `emperor` creates new files (`emperor.log.122568`) after reaching the `log-maxsize` my Vassal files still growing above the `log-maxsize` or in other words nothing happens they don´t create `garden_app.log.56513`.

**So my Question is:** How to set `log-maxsize` for my vassals loggers? Applies `log-maxsize` only to `logto`?

I also tried `logto` or `logto2` on my vassal but then my emperor says "unloyal bad behaving vassal" or "Permission denied".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Solution after looking long into. Now i get separate logs and rotates.

1. change the options from `logger` to `logto` . `logger` will do the log job, but it does not rotate, for whatever reason. Also do not use `file:`.
2. Make sure to make `supervisorctl reread` and `supervisorctl update` after changes on your `uwsgi.ini`

**uwsgi.ini**

```
[program:uwsgi]
command=uwsgi 
    --master 
    --emperor %(ENV_HOME)s/etc/uwsgi/vassals 
    --logto %(ENV_HOME)s/logs/uwsgi/emperor/emperor.log
    --log-maxsize 350000
    --enable-threads

<...autostart etc...>
```

**[garden_app] - vassal**

```
<...>
; ---------
; # Logger #
; ---------
; default req logger and set request Log and - currently disabled 
req-logger = file:%(var_logs)/vassal_garden/garden_request.log
disable-logging = true
log-4xx = true
log-5xx = true
log-maxsize = 350000
; set app / error Log - check
logto = %(var_logs)/vassal_garden/garden_app.log 
log-maxsize = 350000
log-backupname = %(var_logs)/vassal_garden/garden_app.old.log
<...>
```